# Why is the file filename being set to a dot and not when just reading the filenames in the vector?

Tags: c++, file, vector, directory

When iterating the vector with the files, it prints out to the screen each filename in it, but when I call the method readDocument function, the filename becomes a dot. I tested it manually by setting the filename, ex: filename = "collection/file1.txt", it works and reads the file.

Below is the sample code:

```
   
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fstream> 
  
void readDocument(string filePath){ 
    string contents = "";
    string line = ""; 
    filePath = "collection/"+filePath;  
     
    ifstream fileReader(filePath); 
    // opening file  
    if(fileReader.is_open()){
        while( getline(fileReader, line) ){ 
            contents += line;
            cout << contents << endl;
        }   
        fileReader.close();
    }
    else{
        cout << "Could not read file" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }  
    
}

void readDirectory (vector<string> &files)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *dp;

    char cwd[1024];

    getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));

    if((dir  = opendir("collection")) == NULL) {
        perror("\nUnable to open directory.");
        exit(0);
    }
    while ((dp=readdir(dir)) != NULL) { 
            files.push_back(dp->d_name);
    }
    closedir(dir);
}


int main (){ 
    vector<string> files;  
    
    readDirectory(files);

    for(string _filename : files){ 
        readDocument(_filename); /*Doesn't work*/
        // cout << "File Name: "+_filename << endl; /*Works*/
    } 
}
```

Comment: It seems your compiler is not common one because you are using standard libraries without `std::` prefix nor `using` statements. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Directories contain entries for `"."` (current directory) and `".."` (parent directory), you have to ignore them manually.

Comment: @MikeCAT g++ (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0

Answer (score 3):

The first "files" in any directory on a system such as yours are `.` (current directory) and `..` (parent directory).

Nothing "becomes" a dot; that's a valid entry in your filesystem.

Usually you want to filter those out in your code:

```
int main()
{ 
    vector<string> files;  
    
    readDirectory(files);

    for (const string& filename : files)
    {
        // Skip the "special" entries
        if (filename == "." || filename == "..")
           continue;
        
        readDocument(filename);
    } 
}
```

Comment: How can I filter that?
Well, I understand that the dot is a valid entry, but I am just sending the name of the file to the readDocument function. Like, if I just wanna print the file names that are in the vector, works.

Comment: @Mrfrog With an `if` statement, `==` and `continue`?

Comment: `if (_filename == "." || _filename == "..") continue; else readDocument(_filename);` Easy :)

Comment: (Can be shorter obviously)